# How can I get my logger to properly work with iyparallel Cluster?

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, parallel-processing

I am using the python logger for logging information about the program. This is all in the initializer of the class, though in the class `logger` is `self.logger` so I can access it in other class methods.

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger("Video")
logger.setLevel(5)  # DONT SET TO 0, IF SET TO 0 NO LOGS WILL BE LOGGED
if verbose:
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    level = {1: logging.ERROR, 2: logging.WARNING, 3: logging.INFO, 4: logging.DEBUG}[verbose]
    ch.setLevel(level)
    ch_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)-8s - %(message)s")
    ch.setFormatter(ch_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(ch)
    logger.info(f"Verbose Logging Enabled, Level: {level}")
if log_path is not None:
    fh = logging.FileHandler(log_path, mode="w")  # remove mode="w" if you want to append to the log file
    fh.setLevel(5)
    fh_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s | %(funcName)-28s | %(levelname)-8s | %(message)s")
    fh.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(fh)
    logger.info(f"Logging to file: {log_path}")
```

When initializing the cluster with ipyparallel I do the following:

```py
import ipyparallel as ipp
with ipp.Cluster(n=6, log=logger, log_level=50):
    ...
```

Though when running in a jupyter notebook it is printing all the information from the cluster when the logger does not have the handler for printing to console.

I am using python 3.11 and ipyparallel 8.4.1.